# How to get a value from a dictionary using objectForInsensitiveKey in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, dictionary

I had a function in Objective c to get a value of a dictionary passing a key with insensitive key.

My function in Objective c is:

```
-(UIFont *) languageFont {
    NSDictionary * users = @{@"Aaron" : @"English", @"Alice" : @"English", @"John" : @"Brasilian"};

    NSString * countryLaunguage = [users objectForInsensitiveKey:@"Alice"];

    return countryLaunguage;
}
```

How could I translate this function to Swift? Because in a  Dictionary I can't find a similar function that returns a value from key?

Thanks!

Comment: What is objectForInsensitiveKey?

Answer (score 0):

Have a extension of Dictionary and use the feature.

```
  extension Dictionary where Key == String {
        subscript(insensitive key: Key) -> Value? {
            get {
                if let k = keys.first(where: { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(key) == .orderedSame }) {
                    return self[k]
                }
                return nil
            }
            set {
                if let k = keys.first(where: { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(key) == .orderedSame }) {
                    self[k] = newValue
                } else {
                    self[key] = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example:

```
var dict = ["Aaron" : "English", "Alice" : "English", "John" : "Brasilian"]
print(dict[insensitive: "alice"]!) // outputs "English"
```

Hope this answers your query.